# T-SQL how to count amount of money from another table and Uncertain rows dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a table like below, it has a seqno, code and date

```
data table1

seqno       code  date
00009976    44  2010-05-04 00:00:00.000
00021577    4   2010-11-02 15:10:54.193
00021577    4   2011-03-16 16:58:35.880
00021577    44  2011-09-29 00:00:00.000
00003906    44  2012-06-25 00:00:00.000
00029266    3   2011-01-07 08:42:15.407
00029266    4   2011-08-08 15:47:33.337
00029266    44  2011-10-24 00:00:00.000
00012024    4   2011-03-01 09:28:09.790
00012024    44  2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00006521    4   2011-12-28 08:55:23.567
00006521    44  2012-05-17 00:00:00.000
00071790    1   2011-09-02 09:23:33.000
00071790    44  2012-04-23 00:00:00.000
00008720    44  2012-04-03 00:00:00.000
00010872    3   2012-06-25 13:49:50.197
00010872    44  2012-09-11 00:00:00.000
```

and another table like

```
data table2
seqno      NUMBERS   getdate
00009976    504 2010-05-04 00:00:00.000
00009976    53470   NULL
00021577    10000   2010-12-17 00:00:00.000
00021577    5000    2011-01-18 00:00:00.000
00021577    2000    2011-03-16 00:00:00.000
00021577    5000    2011-04-13 00:00:00.000
00021577    3000    2011-04-13 00:00:00.000
00021577    4000    2011-06-15 00:00:00.000
00021577    2000    2011-05-19 00:00:00.000
00021577    3000    2011-05-26 00:00:00.000
00021577    5000    2011-05-26 00:00:00.000
00021577    1000    2011-05-26 00:00:00.000
00021577    5000    2011-05-26 00:00:00.000
00021577    4000    2011-09-07 00:00:00.000
00021577    11649   2011-09-29 00:00:00.000
00003906    38665   NULL
00029266    230 2011-05-06 00:00:00.000
00029266    265 2011-05-11 00:00:00.000
00029266    2400    2011-05-24 00:00:00.000
00029266    11528   2011-09-22 00:00:00.000
00029266    9379    2011-10-20 00:00:00.000
00029266    12310   2011-10-24 00:00:00.000
00012024    4124    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    5600    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    5600    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    5600    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    5600    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    5600    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    5600    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00012024    4972    2012-01-09 00:00:00.000
00006521    3611    2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
00006521    8647    2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
00006521    32413   2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
00006521    137 2012-05-17 00:00:00.000
00071790    50000   2011-10-28 00:00:00.000
00071790    100000  2012-04-23 00:00:00.000
00008720    61250   2012-04-03 00:00:00.000
00010872    19773   2012-07-31 00:00:00.000
00010872    46395   2012-09-11 00:00:00.000
```

Now i use the seqno and date from table1 and sum numbers from table2 and update correct fields to #resulttable by the code, maybe like

```
if code = '3'
begin
    update #resulttable
    set code3 = a.num
    from 
    (select sum(NUMBERS) num
    from #table2
    where seqno = "SEQNO" and getdate between "DATE1 from table1" and "DATE2 from table1"
    ) a
end
else if code = '4'
begin
    update #resulttable
    set code4 = a.num
    from 
    (select sum(NUMBERS) num
    from #table2 
    where seqno = "SEQNO" and getdate between "DATE1 from table1" and "DATE2 from table1"
    ) a
end
```

i don't know how to get each seqno's date1 and date2 to sql statement, and if same seqno have more than two date, i have to sum date2 to date3 and date3 to date4 also

now i use the cursor and GOTO to solve this, but it really slow, my code is like below

```
declare @seqno char(8), @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime, @code1 char(2), @code2 char(2)
DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR select distinct SEQNO from #table11
OPEN user_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @seqno
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
RERUN:
    select top 1 @date1 = exec_date, @code1 = code from #table1 where seqno = @seqno order by getdate
    delete #table1 where exec_year = seqno = @seqno and getdate = @date1
    select top 1 @date2 = exec_date, @code2 = code from #table1 where seqno = @seqno order by getdate
    if @code1 = '1'
    begin
        update #result_table
        set code1 = a.all_pay + ISNULL(code1,0)
        from #result_table t
            inner join
                (select seqno,sum(NUMBER) all_pay
                from #table2 m
                where (m_getdate between @date1 and @date2) 
                group by SEQNO
                ) a on a.SEQNO = t.seqno
        where t.seqno = @seqno
    end
    else if @code1 = '2'
    begin
        update #result_table
        set code2 = a.all_pay + ISNULL(code2,0)
        from #result_table t
            inner join
                (select seqno,sum(NUMBER) all_pay
                from #table2 m
                where (m_getdate between @date1 and @date2) 
                group by SEQNO
                ) a on a.SEQNO = t.seqno    
        where t.seqno = @seqno
    end
if @code2 <> '44'
    GOTO RERUN

FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @seqno
end
CLOSE user_cursor 
DEALLOCATE user_cursor
```

can this code rerwite to normal t-sql code without cursor?

the result should be

```
seqno   code1   code2   code3   code4   code5   code6   code7   code8   code9
21577   NULL    NULL    NULL    60649   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
29266   NULL    NULL    2895    33217   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
12024   NULL    NULL    NULL    42696   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
6521    NULL    NULL    NULL    137 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
71790   150000  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
8720    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
10872   NULL    NULL    66168   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Thank @gordon-linoff give me good suggestion, now my code is like

```
select dd.SEQNO,
SUM(case when code = '1' then numbers end) as code1,
SUM(case when code = '2' then numbers end) as code2,
SUM(case when code = '3' then numbers end) as code3,
SUM(case when code = '4' then numbers end) as code4,
SUM(case when code = '5' then numbers end) as code5,
SUM(case when code = '6' then numbers end) as code6,
SUM(case when code = '7' then numbers end) as code7,
SUM(case when code = '8' then numbers end) as code8,
SUM(case when code = '9' then numbers end) as code9
from #resulttable t
join
(select EXEC_YEAR,EXEC_CASE,EXEC_SEQNO,
    (select top 1 t.code
    from #table1 t
    where t.seqno = m.SEQNO and m.getdate < t.date
    ) as code, numbers
from #table2 m
) dd
on dd.SEQNO = t.seqno
group by dd.SEQNO
```

but the numbers need to be put at pervious date's code, is this possible ?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Post desired output based on your sample data. Consider creating sqlfiddle with your sample data to help those who may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the code from the first table for each row in the second table using a correlated subquery.  Then you can aggregate and pivot them as you like:

```
select t.seqno,
       sum(case when thecode = 'code1' then numbers end) as code1,
       sum(case when thecode = 'code2' then numbers end) as code2,
       . . .
       sum(case when thecode = 'code9' then numbers end) as code9
from (select rt.*,
             (select top 1 code
              from #anothertable at
              where at.date <= rt.m_getdate and at.seqno = rt.seqno
              order by at.date desc
             ) as thecode
      from #resulttable rt
     ) t
group by t.seqno
```

Comment: thanks @gordon, but the date need between date1 and date2, if use at.date <= rt.m_getdate will add too much number.

Comment: and the data should from table1 and table2, #resulttable has nothing at first. maybe pervious edit table name confuse you. i correct it.

Comment: thank @gordon-linoff the code is really help, but here is new problem, is the code field put pervious code possible?